# C - valgrind conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)

Tags: c, malloc, valgrind

proj2.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "duplicate.h"
#include<stdlib.h>
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    if (argc <= 1)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    char **copy = duplicate_args(argc, argv);
    char **p = copy;
    argv++;
    p++;

    //while (*argv) 
    for(int i=0;i<argc-1;i++)
    {
        printf("%s %s\n", argv[i], p[i]);
    }

    free_duplicated_args(argc,copy);
    return 0; 
}
```

duplicate.c:

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdio.h>
char **duplicate_args(int argc, char **argv)
{
    char **arrPointer=(char**)malloc((argc)*sizeof(char*));
    for(int i=0;i<argc;i++)
    {
        // Added one for string terminator '\0'
        arrPointer[i] = (char*)malloc((strlen(argv[i])*(sizeof(char)))+1);
        for(int j=0;j<strlen(argv[i]);j++)
        {
            if(argv[i][j] > 64 && argv[i][j] < 91)
            {
                arrPointer[i][j]=argv[i][j]+32;
            }
            else if(argv[i][j] > 96 && argv[i][j] < 123)
            {
                arrPointer[i][j]=argv[i][j]-32;
            }
            else
            {
                arrPointer[i][j]=argv[i][j];
            }
        }
        arrPointer[i]+= '\0';

    }
    return arrPointer;
}

void free_duplicated_args(int argc,char **copy)
{
/*  while(copy[i])
    {
        free(copy[i]);
        i++;
    }
    free(copy);
    */
    for(int i=0;i<argc;i++)
    {
        free(copy[i]);
    }
    free(copy);
}
```

duplicate.h:

```
char **duplicate_args(int argc, char **argv);

void free_duplicated_args(int argc,char **copy);
```

In my code above the duplicate function first creates an array of pointers (depending upon argc) and then in loop I point each element of overall array to another pointer which holds my duplicated string. I dont have any memory leak but have an error saying I am making jump based on uninitialized value? I am using --track-origins=yes but still not able to figure out why this is happening?

```
┌─[✗]─[root@danial]─[~/Documents/OS/proj2/project]
└──╼ # valgrind --tool=memcheck --track-origins=yes ./proj2 1
==15798== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==15798== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==15798== Using Valgrind-3.14.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==15798== Command: ./proj2 1
==15798==
==15798== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==15798==    at 0x4838CD8: __strlen_sse2 (vg_replace_strmem.c:462)
==15798==    by 0x48B9BEE: vfprintf (vfprintf.c:1638)
==15798==    by 0x48C0815: printf (printf.c:33)
==15798==    by 0x1091F5: main (in /root/Documents/OS/proj2/project/proj2)
==15798==  Uninitialised value was created by a heap allocation
==15798==    at 0x483577F: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:299)
==15798==    by 0x10928E: duplicate_args (in /root/Documents/OS/proj2/project/proj2)
==15798==    by 0x109194: main (in /root/Documents/OS/proj2/project/proj2)
==15798==
1 1
==15798==
==15798== HEAP SUMMARY:
==15798==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==15798==   total heap usage: 4 allocs, 4 frees, 1,050 bytes allocated
==15798==
==15798== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==15798==
==15798== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==15798== ERROR SUMMARY: 1 errors from 1 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Comment: First mistake for general case - you must have *`argc + 1`* pointers, + 1 for the sentinel NULL. Notice that you can modify arguments in place - this is guaranteed, so you need not *copy them*

Comment: Also you should probably use `isupper`, `toupper`, `tolower`

Comment: `arrPointer[i]+= '\0';` is totally utterly wrong.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala that doesnt make sense to me? If I will do argc+1 pointers it will just create 1 extra pointer? I need NULL after every element therefore I am doing +1 in the loop?

Comment: @AnttiHaapala I am not allowed to use extra libraries!

Comment: What extra libraries?! You're using `strlen` of the C standard library!

Comment: You need to append the null terminator properly - simply looping until `j <= strlen(argv[i])` should be sufficient.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala https://linux.die.net/man/3/isupper #include <ctype.h>

Comment: Yes, that belongs to the C standard library. If you've got restrictions you're to mention them in the question and not drop them piecemeal in the comments.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala appending '\0' fixed the problem thanks :)

Comment: btw, `arrPointer[i]+= '\0';` would increment the ith pointer by 0, i.e. do nothing

Comment: @AnttiHaapala yes didnt, I didnt realize that I had to de-reference it first. Thanks

Comment: NO, you have to either copy with `<=` in the `j` loop, or move the declaration for `j` before the loop (e.g. `int j;`) and then `arrPointer[i][j] = 0;` after the `j` loop completes.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed by @AnttiHaapala I just had to appending '\0' inside the for loop.

```
for(int i=0;i<argc;i++)
{
    // Added one for string terminator '\0'
    arrPointer[i] = (char*)malloc((strlen(argv[i])*(sizeof(char)))+1);
    for(int j=0;j<=strlen(argv[i]);j++)
    {
        if(j==strlen(argv[i]))
        {
            arrPointer[i][j]='\0';
            continue;
        }
        if(argv[i][j] > 64 && argv[i][j] < 91)
        {
            arrPointer[i][j]=argv[i][j]+32;
        }
        else if(argv[i][j] > 96 && argv[i][j] < 123)
        {
            arrPointer[i][j]=argv[i][j]-32;
        }
        else
        {
            arrPointer[i][j]=argv[i][j];
        }             
    }
}
```

Comment: `if(j==strlen(argv[i]))
        {
            arrPointer[i][j]='\0';
            continue;
        }` is not needed. `argv[strlen(argv[i])]` is zero already, and would be handled by the `else`.